# How to inject adminhtml values as an array in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to inject all the values of a given path in the configuration as an array. I know I can inject `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` and get it from there using `ScopeConfigInterface::getValue('my_path')` but the problem is I am using a third party library that uses some config values and it expects an array to be injected.

I have worked it around by creating a new class that extends such a library and then call the parent constructor with the objects injected and also passing along an array I extract using `ScopeConfigInterface::getValue('my_path')`. However I would like to inject them directly to avoid unnecessary redundancy code. Any Ideas?

This can be summarized to how can I inject the value returned by a method in the di.xml.

Comment: Any ideas I still do not know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Magento save country and states as array value (multi select input) , but stock in db like this (AT,BR,CA,CH,DE,EE,ES,FI,FR,LT,LV,RO,US) 
for reading the states use this function :
const XML_PATH_STATES_REQUIRED = 'general/region/state_required';

```
public function getCountriesWithStatesRequired($asJson = false)
{
    $value = trim(
        $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_STATES_REQUIRED,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
    );
    $countryList = preg_split('/\,/', $value, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ($asJson) {
        return $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($countryList);
    }
    return $countryList;
}
```

i think this response will open some doors for you ..

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am looking for. I want to use di.xml to inject an array in a virtualtype. As of now, the only way I have figured out how to inject the adminhtml values is by using `ScopeConfigInterface` so I have done a workaround by injecting a ScopeConfigInterface interface into another class that extends the third party class and overwrite the constructor so it arranges my `ScopeConfigInterface` into an array and then call the parent constructor. I am hoping there is a better, way to do so.